# Cant find package manager console in visual studio for mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual studio for mac. I need to install some packages but I can't find package manager console for that.

Visual studio version: Preview 1 (7.0 build 347)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to Xamarin Studio, you have to use its dialog,

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/nuget_walkthrough/

[image]

As there was no cross platform PowerShell, Xamarin Studio lacks of Package Manager Console. It might come one day in Visual Studio for Mac. We will see.

Comment: So no way to view updates and installed packages like in Windows?

Comment: @MattG the design philosophy differs. You should go to solution explorer and check updates of each package references.

Answer (score 43):

### Warning:

A commenter reports this extension crashes VS Community 2019 for Mac version 8.5 (Build 3183). I haven't upgraded to it, so I can't speak to this. Anyone with information/fix/alternate approach, please chime in down in the comments.

### OK:

At least in Visual Studio Community 8.4.8 build 2, you can find it under Visual Studio-->Extensions, using search term "nuget":

[image]

It took me so long to find this I hope it helps someone else find it faster!

Comment: too bad that MS didnt include this in official release like VS 2019 Windows version has

Comment: The extension crashes whole VS (VS Community 2019 for Mac version 8.5 (Build 3183))

Comment: Ah, I'm still on 8.4.8 so I can't speak to that. I'll add a warning.

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the NuGet CLI reference and install it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference

An excerpt from that link provided reads:

> **macOS/Linux**
>
> Behaviors may vary slightly by OS distribution.
>
> 1. Install [Mono 4.4.2 or later](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/).
> 2. Execute the following commands at a shell prompt:
>
>    ```sh
>    # Download the latest stable `nuget.exe` to `/usr/local/bin`
>    sudo curl -o /usr/local/bin/nuget.exe https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe
>    # Give the file permissions to execute
>    sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/nuget.exe
>    ```
> 3. Create an alias by adding the following script to the appropriate file for your OS (typically `~/.bash_aliases or ~/.bash_profile`):
>
>    ```sh
>    # Create as alias for nuget
>    alias nuget="mono /usr/local/bin/nuget.exe"
>    ```
> 4. Reload the shell. Test the installation by entering `nuget` with no parameters. NuGet CLI help should display.

Answer (score 3):

I found a good reference for mac users:

https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions

Thanks for the reference and it works for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Suggest you to edit the answer explaining how this solution works, rather than posting an external link. Check the meta post for a checklist to provide more useful answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Answer (score 2):

step 1 :- open view
step 2 :- select other window  11 number option from top
step 3.:- there you find Nuget package manegar   console options

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).