# Visual Studio For Mac cannot run Powershell with Nuget Package Management extension

Tags: macos, powershell, visual-studio-mac, nuget-package-manager-console

I was trying to use add-migration command within package management console in Visual Studio for Mac, version 8.4.8 (VS Mac). However, Package Management(PM) Console does not come with VS Mac. 
[Cant find package manager console in visual studio for mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086572/cant-find-package-manager-console-in-visual-studio-for-mac)
I followed the above link, and installed Powershell and NuGet Package Management Extensions version 0.21 . The PM console shows up in my VS Mac. But when I opened it, it started giving me error which I pasted below.

I can run PowerShell in mac terminal. But it does not work within VS Mac

```
Disconnected from remote PowerShell host. Reason: Disposed: Reached end of stream.
Disconnected from remote PowerShell host. Reason: Disposed: Reached end of stream.
Unable to restart PowerShell host
Unable to restart PowerShell host
A task was canceled.
NuGet 5.3.0.3
Type 'get-help NuGet' for more information.

Unable to restart PowerShell host
PM> 
Unable to restart PowerShell host
PM> 
Unable to restart PowerShell host
PM> 
Unable to restart PowerShell host

'/Users/myname/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/3.1.2/tools/init.ps1'

Executing script file '/Users/myname/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/3.1.2/tools/init.ps1'...
Write fault on path /[Unknown]
Disconnected from remote PowerShell host. Reason: Disposed: Reached end of stream.
```

Comment: Can you find any errors in the IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory)? The error output you have listed just suggests the PowerShell host console app cannot be run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the attentions.

Today, my VS Mac cannot open my previous project files and show this error

```
Expected 1 export(s) with contract name MonoDevelop.TextEditor.CocoaTextViewImports but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.
```

I think some of my debugging process for this problem caused this new issue. So I decided to reinstall my VS. I  uninstalled VS Mac and all the resources and dependencies files follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall?view=vsmac-2019)

Just remove VS Mac from the application folder is not enough.

After installing the NuGet Package Management Extensions, my PM console shows up without any error, and the new issue also disappear.